# Install Jhipster old version

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to install an old version of jhipster by using the following commands:

```
sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster@3.2
```

or

```
yarn global add generator-jhipster@3.2
```

with the same result:

> "generator-jhipster@3.2.1" has no binaries

And

> bash: jhipster: command not found

I have already tried the following commands without success:

```
yarn global add yo
```

and

```
export PATH="$PATH:yarn global bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin"
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `jhipster`command with JHipster 3.x as it was introduced in version 4.x. You must run it as `yo jhipster`

You can read the archived documentation for version 3.2.1  at https://jhipster.github.io/documentation-archive/v3.2.1/

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting my answer then.

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster@**version**
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install for example: 
`npm install generator-jhipster@2.23.1`,  
 
 then generate jhipster project by typing `yo jhipster`